# pdfmake open() not working when div hidden on page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdfmake

I am using pdfmake in my angular application to print visitor passes containing photo with other details. Its working fine when I have pass layout on HTML page and then print by calling

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
```

But in some cases, I don't want to display pass layout on page. Instead user can directly view pass on generated pdf and take print out.

When I hide that div either by

```
ng-show="vm.showPassDetails"
```

or

```
style="display:none;"
```

I am getting error as

> Uncaught invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)

I can't figure out what's the issue. Please suggest.

Comment: you can use height:0 instead of display:none;

Comment: @veera : this is not working solution, need to find out alternate solution.